# help a n00b understand rails, specifically inheritance, acts_as_nested_set, awesome_nested_set, sortable_element_for_nested_set

Tags: ruby-on-rails, plugins, acts-as-nested-set

hey there, i'm trying to implement a drag and drop interface for a nested set in my first rails project.  i'm new to rails so bear with me.  my code is basically identical to this project:  http://gist.github.com/128779.  my problem is in the partial at this line:

```
<% for child in root.direct_children do %>
```

I'm getting a NoMethodError for `direct_children` which is an instance method of `acts_as_nested_set`, I believe.  At the console if I try to create a new instance of my model, it is likewise unable to access the `acts_as_nested_set` instance methods, so I don't think the problem is in the partial but in the model.

Again, sorry if my terminology is wrong, I'm new to rails.  Anyway, what am I doing wrong?  I've got "`acts_as_nested_set`" in my model, just like the gist example above but my model does not appear to act as a nested set.  How do I go about fixing this?

Thanks!

Here's the code for the model I am using (todo.rb):

```
class Todo < ActiveRecord::Base
  acts_as_nested_set
end
```

And here's the partial:

```
<% content_tag :li, :id => dom_id(root) do %>
    <%= content_tag :span, root.text %>
    <% content_tag :ul do %>
        <% for child in root.direct_children do %>
            <%= render :partial => "tree", :locals => {:root => child}%>
        <%end %>
    <%end unless root.direct_children.empty? %>
<%end%>
```

`root` is passed to the partial from the view like:

```
<%= render :partial => "tree", :locals => {:root => @root} %>
```

and `@root` is defined in the controller like:

```
@root = Todo.find_by_parent_id(nil)
```

Again, the code is mostly copied wholesale with very few modifications from the gist link above.

Comment: What is the `root` you are referring to in the code snippet?

Comment: Also, we need to see more code, such as the model in question.

Comment: Hey, thanks!  I've added the code above, please let me know if there's anything else needed.

Answer (score 1):

A few things:

- Have you checked that you installed the plugin properly? `./script/plugin install git://github.com/rails/acts_as_nested_set.git`
- Have you set up your table properly? Your model needs to have at least the following 3 columns by default (unless you want to override them): `parent_id`, `lft`, `rgt`. Without these `acts_as_nested_set` is going to have a hard time figuring out what's going on. I suggest you read the documentation at the top of [this file](http://github.com/rails/acts_as_nested_set/blob/b0528dedabec6739d715f5a32336b992c0258e0b/lib/active_record/acts/nested_set.rb) because the readme doesn't say squat, nor does that gist for that matter.
- If you've done the above, have you created a root element (not set the `parent_id` to anything) and then added at least one child to it?

  ```
  m = Model.new
  m.title = "My model's title"
  m.save!
  m2 = Model.new
  m2.title = "My child"
  m2.save!
  m.add_child(m2)
  ```

I just did a quick test using the above, and afterwards I was able to do things like `m.root?` and `m.direct_children`. Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

What I make from your title is that you're using quite a bit more than acts_as_nested_set. Try removing some plugins and try again.